# Statistical User-Defined Functions (UDF)

Tags: vba, excel, statistics

### Problem

The following statistical functions were created to calculate statistics of experiments:

- Mean
- Peak to Peak
- Standard Deviation
- Variance
- Mean Absolute Error (MAE)
- Mean Square Error (MSE)
- Root Mean Square Error (RMSE)

So there are some statistics that needs an ideal point and some that doesn't.

The following image contains the data:

[image: Data]

Where there are two columns, the first contains the measured value and the second the quantity that the data repeats.

### Statistical UDFs

Each function will have as input only the first data column and the quantities must be on the right.

#### Mean

The function on G3 is `=MeanArr(C2:C20)`

And the code is:

```
Public Function MeanArr(rng As Range) As Double

    Dim Arr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent
    Dim cell As Range
    With ws
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Offset(0, 1) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 1) - 1
                    Arr(j + i) = cell
                Next i
                j = j + i
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                i = 0
                Arr(j + i) = cell
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        'Mean
        MeanArr= Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Arr)
    End With

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    MeanArr = "Error"
End Function
```

It is [the Arithmetic Mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticMean.html):

[image: Mean]

#### Peak to Peak

The function on G4 is `=PeaktoPeak(C2:C20)`

And the code is:

```
Public Function PeaktoPeak(rng As Range) As Double

    Dim Arr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent
    Dim cell As Range
    With ws
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Offset(0, 1) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 1) - 1
                    Arr(j + i) = cell
                Next i
                j = j + i
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                i = 0
                Arr(j + i) = cell
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        'Peak to Peak
        PeaktoPeak = WorksheetFunction.Max(Arr) - WorksheetFunction.Min(Arr)
    End With

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    PeaktoPeak = "Error"
End Function
```

Peak to Peak is the amplitude of the data, it is the max minus the min.

#### Standard Deviation

The function on G5 is `StdDeviation(C2:C20)`.

```
Public Function StdDeviation(rng As Range) As Double

    Dim Arr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent
    Dim cell As Range
    With ws
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Offset(0, 1) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 1) - 1
                    Arr(j + i) = cell
                Next i
                j = j + i
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                i = 0
                Arr(j + i) = cell
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        'Standard Deviation
        StdDeviation = WorksheetFunction.StDev(Arr)
    End With

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    StdDeviation = "Error"
End Function
```

The [standard deviation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviation.html) is a measure that is used to quantify the amount of variation or dispersion of a set of data values.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

#### Variance

The function on G7 is `=Variance(C2:C20)`

```
Public Function Variance(rng As Range) As Double

    Dim Arr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent
    Dim cell As Range
    With ws
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Offset(0, 1) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 1) - 1
                    Arr(j + i) = cell
                Next i
                j = j + i
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                i = 0
                Arr(j + i) = cell
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        'Var
        Variance = WorksheetFunction.Var(Arr)
    End With

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Variance = "Error"
End Function
```

The [Variance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Variance.html) is the expectation of the squared deviation of a random variable from its mean. Informally, it measures how far a set of (random) numbers are spread out from their average value.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)

#### Mean Absolute Error (MAE)

The function on G6 is `=MAE(C2:C20;B1)`

```
Public Function MAE(rng As Range, ideal As Double) As Double

    Dim Arr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Sum As Double
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent
    Dim cell As Range
    With ws
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Offset(0, 1) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 1) - 1
                    Arr(j + i) = cell
                Next i
                j = j + i
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                i = 0
                Arr(j + i) = cell
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next cell

        'y=y1-t_ideal; %t_ideal is the square wave of ideal communication and y1 the test vector
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Arr(i) = Arr(i) - ideal
        Next i
        '%Absolute Value
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Arr(i) = Abs(Arr(i))
        Next i
        's=sum(se);
        Sum = 0
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Sum = Sum + Arr(i)
        Next i
        'Mean Absolute Error
        MAE = Sum / (UBound(Arr) + 1)
    End With

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    MAE = "Error"
End Function
```

The [Mean Absolute Error](https://medium.com/@ewuramaminka/mean-absolute-error-mae-sample-calculation-6eed6743838a) is a measure of difference between two continuous variables. Consider a scatter plot of n points, where point i has coordinates (xi, yi)... Mean Absolute Error (MAE) is the average vertical distance between each point and the identity line. MAE is also the average horizontal distance between each point and the identity line.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error)

Calculated by the following formula:

[image: MAE]

#### Mean Squared Error (MSE)

The function on G2 is `MSE(C2:C20;B1)`

```
Public Function MSE(rng As Range, ideal As Double) As Double

    Dim Arr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Sum As Double
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent
    Dim cell As Range
    With ws
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Offset(0, 1) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 1) - 1
                    Arr(j + i) = cell
                Next i
                j = j + i
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                i = 0
                Arr(j + i) = cell
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        'y=y1-t_ideal; %t_ideal is the square wave of ideal communication and y1 the test vector
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Arr(i) = Arr(i) - ideal
        Next i
        '%Square Error, where .^ is used to square vector
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Arr(i) = Arr(i) ^ 2
        Next i
        's=sum(se);
        Sum = 0
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Sum = Sum + Arr(i)
        Next i
        'mse=s/n; %Mean Square Error
        MSE = Sum / (UBound(Arr) + 1)

    End With

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    MSE = "Error"
End Function
```

The [Mean Squared Error](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/machine-learning-mean-squared-error-regression-line-c7dde9a26b93/) of an estimator (of a procedure for estimating an unobserved quantity) measures the average of the squares of the errors—that is, the average squared difference between the estimated values and what is estimated.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)

Formula:

[image: MSE]

#### Root Mean Square Deviation (RMSE)

The formula on G1 is `=RMSE(C2:C20;B1)`

```
Public Function RMSE(rng As Range, ideal As Double) As Double

    Dim Arr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Soma As Double, MSE As Double
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent
    Dim cell As Range
    With ws
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Offset(0, 1) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 1) - 1
                    Arr(j + i) = cell
                Next i
                j = j + i
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(cell.Offset(0, 1) + j - 1)
                i = 0
                Arr(j + i) = cell
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        'y=y1-t_ideal; %t_ideal is the square wave of ideal communication and y1 the test vector
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Arr(i) = Arr(i) - ideal
        Next i
        '%Square Error, where .^ is used to square vector
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Arr(i) = Arr(i) ^ 2
        Next i
        's=sum(se);
        Sum = 0
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Sum = Sum + Arr(i)
        Next i
        'mse=s/n; %Mean Square Error
        MSE = Sum / (UBound(Arr) + 1)
        'rmse=sqrt(mse) %Root Mean Square Error
        RMSE = Sqr(MSE)
    End With

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    RMSE = "Error"
End Function
```

[Root Mean Square Deviation (RMSE)](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Esusan/courses/s60/split/node60.html) is a frequently used measure of the differences between values (sample or population values) predicted by a model or an estimator and the values observed.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation)

Formula:

[image: RMSE]

### Questions

- How is the performance? Can it improve?
- Are the results ok? Are the functions working properly?
- How to make a proper `ErrHandler`?
- Should i use `WorksheetFunction` or created my own UDFs? If the quantity of data gets really large.
- I was thinking... Should I use a Global Array for each Sheet? So it doesn't have to calculate an array of data for each function again?
- Further tips/help are welcome. Or another improvements.

Just for reference:

- [MAE and RMSE — Which Metric is Better?](https://medium.com/human-in-a-machine-world/mae-and-rmse-which-metric-is-better-e60ac3bde13d)
- [How to compare models](http://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/compare.htm)

Comment: Be aware there are 2 different formulas for stddev, one for a population and one for a sample space. This also have an effect on related formulas, like variance and stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas on improvements you can make in the overall code, presented in an example for one of the math functions. The ideas can be applied to all the other functions as well.

My lead-in to the rest of my comments and examples primarily deal with highly repeated logic in all of your functions. A big clue is when you end up copying a section of code into another function, you should STOP and consider creating a single common function. This "functional isolation" of logic makes your code more consistent and greatly helps when changes need to be made to the logic. You only have to make the change in once place.

So my first comments deals with your input range to all your functions. Each function seems to require a two-column range with both values and quantities. This is perfectly fine, but if that's the case then your input range should also be a two-column range. Your example accepts a one-column range and uses `Offset` to check the quantity value. This is a mis-match between what you **think** is the input range: single-column, but really using two. So bottom line is to make your input range match what the UDF is actually using.

Along those lines, each UDF should perform checks against the input values to ensure they match the expectations of your function. In my example below, I've created an `InputCheck` function that can be called from each of your UDFs, providing central (and functionally isolated) checks on your input data. My example only shows two quick checks, but you can add any other checks/tests as needed. I highly recommend reading [Chip Pearson's Returning Errors From User Defined Functions In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx) for guidance. Returning errors from UDFs in this manner means that "error handling" won't stop execution or use a pop-up `MsgBox` -- any error will be indicated in the cell.

```
Private Function InputCheck(ByRef dataRange As Variant) As Long
    '--- returns 0 if all checks pass!!

    '--- input must be a range
    If Not TypeName(dataRange) = "Range" Then
        InputCheck = xlErrRef
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--- input range must be one or two columns ONLY
    If (dataRange.Columns.Count < 1) Or (dataRange.Columns.Count > 2) Then
        InputCheck = xlErrRef
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--- all cells MUST contain numeric values
    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In dataRange
        If Not IsNumeric(cell) Then
            InputCheck = xlErrNum
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell

    '--- create any other checks for valid input data...

    '--- everything looks good!
    InputCheck = 0
End Function
```

*(You'll notice that I'm sneaking in an extra check I'll show later. But basically it's if the UDF is called with a single column of data everything will still work.)*

Now you can create a common block at the beginning of each of your UDFs that will return a valid error code to the worksheet cell:

```
    Dim checkResult As Long
    checkResult = InputCheck(dataRange)
    If checkResult <> 0 Then
        QtyMean = CVErr(checkResult)
        Exit Function
    End If
```

Your next section of common logic builds an array of values from the input data, including repeating values based on the quantity indicator. I've also moved this logic into its own isolated function.

One step in speed improvement is to perform most of your logic in memory-based arrays instead of directly interacting with the worksheet or range object. So the first thing to do is move the input range to an array. You can then make a quick check and if it's a single-column, then you're all done. If there are two columns, the logic proceeds almost identically to your original code. Note that you can pre-determine the size of your return array by summing the quantities in the second column. This avoids the expense of `ReDim Preserve` during code execution.

```
Private Function GetDataArray(ByRef srcRange As Variant) As Variant
    Dim theSourceData As Variant
    theSourceData = srcRange.Value
    If srcRange.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        '--- only one column, so we're done!
        GetDataArray = theSourceData
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--- we're building a single array and (possibly) repeating values
    '    based on the quantity indicator in the second column, so...

    '--- size the results array first...
    Dim resultsSize As Long
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(theSourceData, 1) To UBound(theSourceData, 1)
        resultsSize = resultsSize + theSourceData(n, 2)
    Next n

    Dim resultArray() As Variant
    ReDim resultArray(0 To resultsSize)

    '--- ... now build the array and repeat values as necessary
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For n = LBound(theSourceData, 1) To UBound(theSourceData, 1)
        If theSourceData(n, 2) > 1 Then
            '--- repeat values in the array
            For i = 0 To theSourceData(n, 2) - 1
                resultArray(j + i) = theSourceData(n, 1)
            Next i
            j = j + i
        ElseIf theSourceData(n, 2) = 1 Then
            '--- only a single value
            i = 0
            resultArray(j + i) = theSourceData(n, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next n
    GetDataArray = resultArray
End Function
```

Since this function returns a well-crafted array of values, the only thing left is the math logic. So my example UDF for calculating the Mean is

```
Public Function QtyMean(ByRef dataRange As Variant) As Double
    '--- accepts a one- or two-column range where column 1 holds the
    '    values and (the optional) column 2 holds the quantities
    Dim checkResult As Long
    checkResult = InputCheck(dataRange)
    If checkResult <> 0 Then
        QtyMean = CVErr(checkResult)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim dataWithQty As Variant
    dataWithQty = GetDataArray(dataRange)

    If IsArray(dataWithQty) Then
        QtyMean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataWithQty)
    Else
        QtyMean = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End Function
```

Some end notes on the example code:

- Most parameters are passed as `Variant` because it forces (reminds) me to perform all input error checking in my UDF and supporting functions. Excel will convert some inputs for you, but can't always know exactly what you're expecting and which appropriate error should be raised.
- Use more descriptive names for your variables. It makes the code more readable and self-documenting. As an example, your `Arr` array variable is not hard to figure out but when I use `resultArray` it makes more sense when "reading" the code.
- Each of your functions consistently sets up a worksheet variable `ws` but never uses it. I can recommend a tool such as [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) that can help with code quality checks like this. (Disclaimer:  I have nothing to do with Rubberduck, just a satisfied user)

Here's the whole example module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function QtyMean(ByRef dataRange As Variant) As Double
    '--- accepts a one- or two-column range where column 1 holds the
    '    values and (the optional) column 2 holds the quantities
    Dim checkResult As Long
    checkResult = InputCheck(dataRange)
    If checkResult <> 0 Then
        QtyMean = CVErr(checkResult)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim dataWithQty As Variant
    dataWithQty = GetDataArray(dataRange)

    If IsArray(dataWithQty) Then
        QtyMean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataWithQty)
    Else
        QtyMean = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetDataArray(ByRef srcRange As Variant) As Variant
    Dim theSourceData As Variant
    theSourceData = srcRange.Value
    If srcRange.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        '--- only one column, so we're done!
        GetDataArray = theSourceData
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--- we're building a single array and (possibly) repeating values
    '    based on the quantity indicator in the second column, so...

    '--- size the results array first...
    Dim resultsSize As Long
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(theSourceData, 1) To UBound(theSourceData, 1)
        resultsSize = resultsSize + theSourceData(n, 2)
    Next n

    Dim resultArray() As Variant
    ReDim resultArray(0 To resultsSize)

    '--- ... now build the array and repeat values as necessary
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For n = LBound(theSourceData, 1) To UBound(theSourceData, 1)
        If theSourceData(n, 2) > 1 Then
            '--- repeat values in the array
            For i = 0 To theSourceData(n, 2) - 1
                resultArray(j + i) = theSourceData(n, 1)
            Next i
            j = j + i
        ElseIf theSourceData(n, 2) = 1 Then
            '--- only a single value
            i = 0
            resultArray(j + i) = theSourceData(n, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next n
    GetDataArray = resultArray
End Function

Private Function InputCheck(ByRef dataRange As Variant) As Long
    '--- returns 0 if all checks pass!!

    '--- input must be a range
    If Not TypeName(dataRange) = "Range" Then
        InputCheck = xlErrRef
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--- input range must be one or two columns ONLY
    If (dataRange.Columns.Count < 1) Or (dataRange.Columns.Count > 2) Then
        InputCheck = xlErrRef
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--- all cells MUST contain numeric values
    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In dataRange
        If Not IsNumeric(cell) Then
            InputCheck = xlErrNum
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell

    '--- create any other checks for valid input data...

    '--- everything looks good!
    InputCheck = 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard public announcement: always include `Option Explicit` at the top of modules.

### How to improve performance

Two tips here:

- Put your range into an array and work with the array, not Excel
  objects. The switching between Excel and VBA models is computationally expensive.
- Avoid wherever possible `ReDim`ming and `Preserve`-ing arrays. They are computationally expensive.

To use your first function as an example

```
Public Function MeanArr(rng As Range) As Double '<-- I will make a comment about this later
'Error checks required for if the user selected a single cell, or if they selected more than one column.

    Dim initialValues as Variant '<-- create an array here
    Dim initialQuantities as Variant '<-- be explicit with all values you want to use
    initialValues = rng.Value 
    initialQuantities = rng.Offset(0,1).Value
    'Dim Arr() ' <-- This would have been an array of variants, which is subtly different 
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim totalSum as Double, totalCount as Double 
    For j = LBound(initialValues,1) to UBound(initialValues,1)
        'Error checking required for valid input - is it really a Number?
        totalCount = totalCount + CDbl(initialQuantities(j,1))
        totalSum = totalSum + CDBL(initialValues(j,1)) * CDbl(initialQuantities(j,1))

    Next j
    MeanArr = totalSum / totalCount

    Exit Function '<--- left this here for now but will address errors later.
ErrHandler:
    MeanArr = "Error" '<-- I will make a comment about this later

End Function
```

You don't use `ws` (yes, you have a `With` statement, but how the code is written, that `With` is not used. Nor is it needed!

I was going to use a Collection instead of an expanding array - but turns out not necessary in this case. However, for the more complex formulae, consider using a Collection instead of an array, or try to resize the array only once at the beginning. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56842847/9101981

### Are the functions working correctly?

I don't know - I hope they are otherwise this post is off-topic and I am wasting my time on this response! However, you can derive tests to ensure your own correctness.

### Proper error handling

You are creating a UDF - Let Excel do some of the work for you.

```
Public Function MeanArr(rng As Range) As Variant '<-- significant
'Error checks required for if the user selected a single cell, or if they selected more than one column.

    If rng.Columns.Count > 1 then
        MeanArr = CVErr(xlErrName)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim initialValues as Variant '<-- create an array here
    Dim initialQuantities as Variant '<-- be explicit with all values you want to use
    initialValues = rng.Value 
    initialQuantities = rng.Offset(0,1).Value

    Dim j As Long
    Dim totalSum as Double, totalCount as Double 
    For j = LBound(initialValues,1) to UBound(initialValues,1)
        'Error checking required for valid input - is it really a Number?
        If Not IsNumeric() or Not IsNumeric() Then
            MeanArr = CVErr(xlErrNum)
            Exit Function
        End If
        totalCount = totalCount + CDbl(initialQuantities(j,1))
        totalSum = totalSum + CDBL(initialValues(j,1)) * CDbl(initialQuantities(j,1))

    Next j
    MeanArr = CDbl(totalSum / totalCount)
' Error handling is now done in the code logic.    
End Function
```

Leaving the function return type as Variant is deliberate, it means that you can control what is returned and use the in-built error types to indicate to your user any issues. It also means that if you link the results cell to any other cell, Excel knows how to handle chained errors. Excel might misinterpret a random string ("error") potentially hiding issues from the user if you didn't use the built in types.

### Use Worksheet functions?

This is an 'it depends' answer. For speed, writing your own routines will generally be faster. However, some of the more complex functions, using the built in worksheet function may be easier. Trade off against your own requirements, just remember that every switch to the Excel model costs.

### Use Global Array?

Definitely not. You are writing portable, reusable UDFs which take a range as a parameter. Using a global variable just ties you down with no flexibility.